# Winsock not connecting to WAN IP addresses

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock

I'm wondering if anyone can give me reasons why Winsock is not connecting to WAN IP addresses.
It only connects to my LAN IP address or the looping address 127.0.0.1.

I'm running the client and the server on the same computer. I first run the server program, then verify that it is in fact listening on 0.0.0.0::3307 from the command prompt, then make the appropriate port forwarding by routing port 3307 to the computer in my LAN running the server. But it still cannot connect. I have also restarted my router.

What could be causing my client not to connect to the server running on the same computer?

Comment: if you are trying to connect to the public IP:port of firewall/NAT/router from the same private network that your server is running on, you're expecting your network device to "hairpin" the connection which it may not support.  try connecting to your server from some "off network / public" device to see if your network device is forwarding correctly in the "normal" sense.

Answer (score 0):

I guess 0.0.0.0 as listening Adress is the Problem here.
May you inform yourself about IP address rooms and reserved addresses in detail.
Not quite shure, if i got you right here, but if you're able to get a connection using localhost's address or LAN IP Address everything's allright.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is just the default address to which Winsock attaches. I don't believe you can change this.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 just means "bind to all available addresses" - that's not the problem.